# Display specific number of characters

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I have list with field "Description" and it´s `text-area` with 10 rows field, so when I create an item in NewForm it´s ok, problem is when it is displayed on main view, because it´s a large column, is it possible to reduce that column to show only first 80 characters? Is there a option to do that? or is it possible to do with JS in a command secuence editor? Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using pure CSS:

```
.ms-rtestate-field {     
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Demonstration:
[image]

**(Update)**
If you need two lines. The drawback of this sample is that it does not show ellipses at the end:

```
.ms-rtestate-field { 
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 400px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  height: 3em;
  overflow: hidden;  
}
```

**Update 2**

**Using CSR (JSLINK)**

- Install [Cisar Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en)
- Navigate to your SharePoint list
- Press F12 and click on the new "Cisar" tab
- On the left hand side enter a name of your new JSLINK file
- Find the JSON node that says "Templates" and replace it's consents with the snippet below. instead of "Description" type your field's internal name.

  ```
    Templates: {
     Fields: {
         "Description": {                     
             View: function(ctx) { 
               var fieldValue = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
               if(fieldValue && fieldValue.length>80){
                  return  ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name].substring(0,80) + '...'; 
               }else{
                 return fieldValue;
               }                  

             }                   
         }
     },
  ```

  - click "Publish" when done

[image]

Sample of the code:
[image]

[image]

Comment: from where you get field name? your field have class .ms-rtestate-field by default?

Comment: .ms-rtestate-field is a class name used for all multiline text fields. it's not the name of my field.

Comment: and what about if I want to show more than one line, I mean show 80 characters without resize column. Is that possible?

Comment: If you need some complex logic that cannot be done using CSS - it's easier to do it JSLINK, Client Side Rendering. I've updated my answer. You can insert any JavaScript logic there.